# One fixture with 2 switching locations

Tags: electrical, lighting, dimmer-switch

I have  a fixture that switches from 2 locations.  I am installing dual dimmers on this fixture.  the dimmers are a master / slave dimmer setup.  I have found the traveler wires (red and black)  the other wires available from the old switches are black and ground (bare) wires.  The whites are all tied together.  Do i need to open the white wires and bring out a white lead to the new dimmers?  the master dimmer has 7 wires (Leviton (bluetooth) DD710-BD).  Will I need all seven leads?

Answer (score 1):

> **Will I need all seven leads?**

Yes, for a three-way setup you need all seven.

[image: installation diagram from makers instructions]

---

> **Do I need to open the white wires and bring out a white lead to the new dimmers?**

Yes

[image: extract from installation guide]

Comment: Note: *ADD* the dimmer white to the white bundle.  Do not "bring out a white" from the bundle.